# Add child element in xml using XmlDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add a child elements below root elements but to be the first child elements. My current xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
 <testsuite name="classname" tests="9" failures="3" errors="6" time="2919" disabled="0" skipped="0">
  <testcase name="Setup1" time="5" classname="classname">
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Setup2" time="49" classname="classname">
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Setup3" time="357" classname="classname">
  </testcase>
 </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

After add the element , i want it look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
 <properties name ="namedata" value="valuedata">
 </properties>
  <testsuite name="classname" tests="9" failures="3" errors="6" time="2919" disabled="0" skipped="0">
   <testcase name="Setup1" time="5" classname="classname">
   </testcase>
   <testcase name="Setup2" time="49" classname="classname">
   </testcase>
   <testcase name="Setup3" time="357" classname="classname">
   </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

What i did is

```
XmlDocument report = new XmlDocument();
report.Load(fileOfReport);
XmlElement root = report.CreateElement("properties");
root.SetAttribute("property name", "namedata");
root.SetAttribute("value","valuedata");
var items = report.GetElementsByTagName("testsuite");
for(int i=0; i<items.Count; i++){
    child.AppendChild(items[i]);
}
report.AppendChild(root);
report.Save(fileOfReport);
```

The code shows properties as a root elements which include testsuite, but actually i want it as a child elemetns which is parallel with testsuite. How should i re-structure that?
Note, i can only use xmlDocument not xDocument

Thanks

Comment: Attribute name can't contain a space. That's what `0x20` is. Change `property name` to `propertyName` and it should work just fine.

Comment: First validate the XML you're using. And then add the new child to it.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJuraszek. Your answer is right. I correct it. But i have another issue. I update the question already. Thank you very much

Comment: `<propertyname ="namedata" value="valuedata">` is **not** xml.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thanks for your advice. I correct it. Sorry, i am still new to XML area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlDocument` has plenty of useful methods. In this case, the `PrependChild` is convenient.

```
XmlDocument report = new XmlDocument();
report.Load(fileOfReport);

XmlElement root = report.CreateElement("properties");
root.SetAttribute("propertyname", "namedata");
root.SetAttribute("value", "valuedata");

report.DocumentElement.PrependChild(root);

report.Save(fileOfReport);
```

Comment: Looks like PrependChild is the right methods to call. But i run your solution, it is still missing <properties> </properties> in the xml. it only shows <properties value property name>

Comment: @JiangJiali - I just copied your code creating the element. Show valid xml, so I can write the code of its creation. Your xml in the question is incorrect.

Comment: Please look the second section of my xml file, that is what I want.